Logical replication fails with "publisher did not send replica identity column expected by the logical replication target relation <table>"
I have two postgre databases where one is set to publish a table and the other subscribes to it for logical replication. This is setup in PgAdmin.
This is a simple test case, and the table i'm replicating is simply:
CREATE TABLE public.test_gen_key (
    num int8 NOT NULL,
    uid varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((num * 10))) STORED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_gen_key_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

The important part of this is that the uid column is always generated (using an expression that multiplies the value of the num column by 10).
Replicating this table works fine for INSERTs, but it fails for DELETEs with the error:
2024-06-12 14:32:37.064 ACST [4828] ERROR:  publisher did not send replica identity column expected by the logical replication target relation "public.test_gen_key"

2024-06-12 14:32:37.064 ACST [4828] CONTEXT:  processing remote data for replication origin "pg_51223" during message type "DELETE" for replication target relation "public.test_gen_key" in transaction 7829, finished at 0/37A8E50

Why does the DELETE statement fail due to no replica identity being given? The uid primary key should be there, so why isn't it using this?
